# Homology with coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

i am starting to study homology groups and i have a question, maybe is a dumb question but if someone could help me would be great.
The question is

$H_i(X,A)=H_i(X,A;\mathbb{Z})?$

I mean equal or isomorphic, i think that the answer is yes(it seems obvious at least for me) but i may be wrong so if someone could tell if i am right or not before i continue reading further, thanks

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: how can something be obvious to you and at the same time you do not know if you are right?! I vote to restrict the usage of the word *obvious* to things you know for sure!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez i didn´t said that was obvious, i said that "seems obvious", many times you can think that something is obvious but it turns out that it wasn´t true at all. Considering that i am starting to learn about homology i prefer to doubt about the things that seems "obvious" but i don´t have a proof...

Comment: Well, my point is that something cannot *seem obvious* if you are not sure it is true!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, usually when writing $H_*(X,A)$ without specifying a coefficient group, then you implicitly mean $H_*(X,A;\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: There is more to it: this convention is coherent. Indeed, if we write $H_*(X,A;G)$ the homology with coefficients in an abelian group $G$, then we can compute $H_*(X,A;\mathbb Z)$. On the other hand, by taking the homology of the singular complex without introducing coefficients, we get something that we might write $H_*(X,A)$. The point is that these two things are canonically isomorphic.

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that for all abelian groups $M$ there is a natural isomorphism $M\cong M\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Z$, and in particular the isomorphism is not a purely notational fact :-)